# Javascript Date object returns 'invalid date' for my date string

Tags: javascript, date

I want to create a Date object in Javascript using this string `04/21/2014 12:00p`
When passed to the constructor (`new Date('04/21/2014 12:00p')`), it returns `Invalid Date`.

I've seen other posts which manipulate the string in order to fulfill the requirements of a valid dateString, however that is not what I want.  I want Javascript to recognize my date format (`m/dd/yy h:mmt`).  In Java, something like that is simple, I imagine that there would be a similar way in Javascript.

How can I get the Date object to recognize my format?

Comment: If you don't want to split your date into pieces and work with them manually, you must use a library which does it for you. But AFAIK there's no way to do it natively.

Comment: You could extend the native object to accept the Java format and build a valid date object, that way you only need to do it in code one time..

Comment: another common method is to pass the milliseconds of the date and use that in the constructor instead of a string

Comment: @Brett do you mean convert the date string to an epoch value?  How would I get the that from a string?

Comment: Do you have access to the date object in you Java code? if so, switching your mechanism of passing that date as a string to passing it as a double representing the milliseconds since January 1, 1970 (epoch value). This elliminates the headaches other than normalizing it to local time, which is another issue in itself

Comment: I rather not use Java code in my Javascript. I would like to keep it native.  Date has function called `parse` which I could use, but it doesn't like the `a` or `p` at the end which prevents it from converting it to epoch.  I guess string manipulation is the best and easiest way to do this.

Comment: You wouldn't have to use Java code in the javascript, just give the value to the javascript somehow, such as through a hidden field or ajax method. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is trivial only when using a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
var dt = moment("04/21/2014 12:00p","MM/DD/YYYY h:mma").toDate();
```

Otherwise, you would have considerable string manipulation to do.  Also you would have to account for users in parts of the world that use m/d/y or other formatting instead of the y/m/d formatting of your input string.

If this string is being sent from some back-end process, you might consider changing the format to a standard interchange format like [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) instead.  Ex.  `"2014-04-21T12:00:00"`

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate the string in order to fulfill the requirements, could be a way, but you need to take care of all browser issues.

A more quick and dirty way is use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library. It helps on formatting matters too.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (String.prototype.dateFromJava == null)
{
   String.prototype.fromJava = function (sDateString)
   {
      var aDateOrTime = sDateString.splt(" ");
      var aDateParts  = aDateOrTime[0].split("/");
      var aTimeParts  = aDateOrTime[1].split(":");
      var oDate       = null;  

      /* just get the pieces and passing them in to new Date(), return oDate */ 
   }
}
```