# javascript Date() object returns valid but not new Date()

Tags: javascript

var `d = Date("12:00 AM")` returns as a date just fine, however when trying to create an instance of it `new Date("12:00 AM")` it returns 'Invalid date'.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279547/javascript-date-object-returns-invalid-date-for-my-date-string), using moment.js, which works fine, but I would like know why getting 'Invalid Date' when using 'new Date()'

Thanks

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud0u70wt/)

Comment: `Date()` (without `new`) does not take a parameter and just yields the current date as a string

Comment: `12:00 AM` is only a time, not a date, and therefore too less information to make a valid datetime. What output would you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN:

> Note: Note that JavaScript `Date` objects can only be instantiated by
>   calling JavaScript `Date` as a constructor: calling it as a regular
>   function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather
>   than a `Date` object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript
>   `Date` objects have no literal syntax.
>
> ...
>
> Invoking JavaScript `Date` as a function (i.e., without the new
>   operator) will return a string representing the current date and time.

The first version of your call ignores the argument (and doesn't actually produce a Date).